# How do I write an iOS Push Notification server with .NET

Tags: .net, iphone, ipad, ios

Is there a good example on how to implement a PUSH NOTIFICATION to my iPhone using a .net server side code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a link to get you started:
http://code.google.com/p/apns-sharp/